# Ajax call stops halfway through code

Tags: ajax, vb.net

```
<AjaxPro.AjaxMethod(AjaxPro.HttpSessionStateRequirement.Read)> _
Public Function HandleSelect(ByVal table As String, ByVal eventSource As String, ByVal filterValue As String, ByVal targetControl As String) As StreetNameResponse

    Dim tName As TableName
    Dim filter As String = Nothing
    Dim sort As String = Nothing
    Dim textField As String = Nothing
    Dim valueField As String = Nothing
    Dim name As String = Nothing
    Dim onChange As String = Nothing
    'Assign security filter
    CheckSecurityFilter()

    Select Case table.ToLower
        Case "county"
            tName = TableName.County
            If filterValue = "-1" Or filterValue = "" Then
                If _restrictionLevel = RestrictionLevel.District Then
                    filter = _restrictionFilter
                End If
            Else
                filter = String.Format("maintdisnmbr in ({}0)", filterValue)
            End If
            tName = TableName.County
            sort = "countyname ASC"
            textField = "countyname"
            valueField = "countynmbr"
            name = "selCounty"
            onChange = "CheckSubmitEnabled();ajaxGetSelect('city','county', this, 'spanCity')"
        Case "city"
            If filterValue = "-1" Or filterValue = "" Then
                'No value selected, set the filter to the default security value
                If _restrictionLevel = RestrictionLevel.District Or _restrictionLevel = RestrictionLevel.County Then
                    filter = _restrictionFilter
                End If
            Else
                Select Case eventSource.ToLower
                    Case "district"
                        filter = String.Format("maintdisnmbr in ({0})", filterValue)
                    Case "county"
                        filter = String.Format("countynmbr in ({0})", filterValue)
                End Select
            End If

            tName = TableName.MasterCity
            sort = "sams_cityname ASC"
            textField = "sams_cityname"
            valueField = "cityname_value"
            name = "selCity"
            onChange = "CheckSubmitEnabled()"
    End Select
    Dim selOutput As HtmlSelect = BuildSelect(tName, filter, sort, textField, valueField, name, onChange)
    Dim outControl As New StreetNameResponse
    outControl.targetControl = targetControl
    outControl.outputControl = selOutput
    MyBase.ProperCaseSelectControl(selOutput)
    Return outControl
End Function
```

In the above code I am having issue debugging. The point of this is in the HTML I have three select tags. District, County, and City. If you select a District it should update County and City to limit only the Counties or Cities in that District. City works perfectly but County does not. I discovered that when running through this code above if it runs through the County Case segment it just stops filter = String.Format("maintdisnmbr in ({}0)", filterValue). If I step through step by step the code does not finish. If I don't go step by step and jump ahead it gives me an error saying the Input string is not formatted. This is not my code and I have not worked with Ajax but I have to fix it please any help to at least figure out the issue would be great.

Comment: This looks like it will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Bad code monkey. No cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> "maintdisnmbr in ({}0)"

Should look like this instead:

> "maintdisnmbr in ({0})"

But that's *if* you want to be vulnerable to sql injection. If you want good code, you'll read  this series of articles on correctly passing a list to sql server:

> http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Comment: while right now I am just trying to get the code working...We had a team leave and so everyone on this project did not write the code we are just trying to get it working. We will refractor later. Thanks for pointing out the simple mistake that I overlooked.